# MySQL Usernames Listed in ONE Field Inside of a Table To Query Another Table and Return User Results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I am new to PHP and I have been on a roll lately developing a website. My question is this. I have all users listed inside of a field in one table.

This is a list of one of these fields: admin, user1, user2, user3.

Now what I need to do is take them users from that ONE field, I am guessing put them into an array and then search each user inside of another table called users and then list the users info such as their rating and bio.

I reposted this with pictures to help you get an idea of what I am looking to accomplish.

I am looking to get the users from this table listed inside of that cell
[jobs Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWEOr.png)

and find them in this table and then list them
[users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAUQB.png)

Hey I have edited the code in the following way and I am getting an error.

```
$jobID = 1;
$jq = $con-> prepare('SELECT applied_names FROM jobs WHERE jobID=1 LIMIT 1');
$jq-> execute();
$jq-> bind_result($usernames);
$jq-> fetch();
$jq-> close();

$stm = $con->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username IN (?)");
$stm->execute(array($usernames));
$result = $stm->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
$stm->close();
```

The warning says:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given on line 14

Comment: you can write sub queries.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: So after I get these usernames from the one field I am thinking that I somehow need to parse them as they are only separated by a comma

Comment: These usernames are not in different fields for this particular table. However in the other table that I want to search the usernames in after getting them they are in different fields

Comment: I would highly recommend using a link table... something called user_jobs and link them that way where you would have 3 columns, id,userID and jobID, this way will make all your future queries much easier to work with

Comment: @LiamG You know what liam I was thinking of that but thought it would bog it down too much. Being new to PHP and programming in general I though that maybe I was missing some kind of magic bullet for this but I think you hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Do you wanna answer this question so that I can mark it answered and give you credit for it. I feel relieved that this is the way to go and it will still not fall into the 'bad practice' category as I am working very hard to follow good practices from the get go and not have to re-learn all this again later

Comment: Also Liam, Let me ask you something. if this were to be a big site (theoretically) would a link table bog it down?

Comment: @JosephAlvini I have updated my answer so that it will work with this current set up

Comment: @JosephAlvini no the link table would do the opposite, you are going to have to do much more work parsing data in PHP to make even the simplest of queries possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery and the keyword `IN` for this:

`SELECT * FROM meta_table WHERE userID IN (SELECT id FROM users)`

If you post table & column names, I will be able to give you a more precise query.

**EDIT:**
after seeing your edited post with the images, this way is not possible. you would still be able to use the `IN` after you have got the field with the usernames in PHP.

```
$usernames = $row['applied_names'];
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN (?)");
$stm->execute(array($usernames));
```

And for mysqli:

```
$usernames = $row['applied_names'];
$stm = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN (?)");
$stm->bind_param('s', $usernames);
$stm->execute();
```

In my opinion, you should have a `users_jobs` table with columns `id` `userID` & `jobID` then you can use queries like this:

```
SELECT username,email,jobName,jobStatus FROM users_jobs 
JOIN users ON users.id = users_jobs.userID
JOIN jobs ON jobs.id = users_jobs.jobID
```

This will produce one row with all the columns you have specified in the `SELECT`

Comment: hey I am getting an error when trying to implement your code. I have added my code above. Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: my example was using PDO, I would recommend checking that out! For your mysqli example, see my edit above

Answer (score 0):

Just try that :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT name, rating, bio  FROM Users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "name: " . $row["name"]. " - rating: " . $row["rating"]. "bio " . $row["bio"]. "....<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: he says he need to search data with the usernames in another table.

Comment: Yes he is right I do need to search the usernames in another table

Comment: Ow sorry, so just use subquery as they say above

Comment: And I also have to parse said usernames from the first table which I think can be done with explode but I cannot figure out how to get them to search the second table after exploding them. I can get the usernames to echo out but that it

Comment: No don't the things in that way. Using sub queries, you can simply get data of each user where data and usernames are in different tables.
Do some research on sub queries or you can try the answer said by @LiamG

Comment: @VAMSIkRISHNA hey take a look at the pictures I added and ow it is set up. Will this work with multiple users being in one cell

Comment: sorry! i was away. Hope your problem is resolved as you marked the answer. @JosephAlvini

Comment: @Vamsi Krishna that would've worked if it was only one table but I used a JOIN statement to join the 2 tables then query the user fields that I need

Comment: Yeah that's what you need to do. You need to join the tables first and then write the user fields in where condition.